# Best way to modularize a block of JSP code

Tags: java, jsp

I have a block of JSP code that needs to be used in several places (basically a widget that several pages use). What's a good way to modularize this? I'd rather not put it in an object since string manipulation of HTML gets ugly. Using `<%@ include file="foo.jsp"%>` is problematic because we wind up having implicit global vars.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can create a simple *tag* and use it anywhere you want your widget. A tag is a reusable object that you can use in any of your JSP's.

Please see http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/JSPTags.html.

Comment: The url is not validated any more.

Answer (score 4):

1. Separate the JSP out into its own file and include it (JSP Includes, Tiles Includes, etc)
2. Can you create a Tag Lib incorporating the functionality?

Answer (score 3):

In JSP 2, custom tags were improved. Here's a [good article](http://www.vsj.co.uk/java/display.asp?id=408) on them.

Previously, JSP isn't very good at modularizing code, includes and tag libs, the two options you discounted, are about it. Custom tags before JSP 2, which [Bogdan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/281624/best-way-to-modularize-a-block-of-jsp-code#281634) points you to, are powerful, but have an overhead.